# Average time of difference of two dates in hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

How can I find the average time for a difference of two dates in hours?

This is my variant, but the output can not be grouped only by name.

```
SELECT NAME, DATEDIFF(HOUR, START_DATE, END_DATE)
FROM [dbo].[DB1]
GROUP BY NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE
```

Example:

```
1 DAY
START_DATE 2017-05-02 05-00-00-000
END_DATE   2017-05-03 00-00-00-000
RESULT: 7 HOURS

2 DAY 
START_DATE 2017-05-02 07-00-00-000
END_DATE   2017-05-03 12-00-00-000
RESULT: 5 HOURS

AND AVG RESULT = 6
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: Why don't you want to group only by name? It can't work if you group by start and/or end date. NB: The first difference should be 19, not 7.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the `DATEDIFF` in a subquery, then average that:

```
SELECT
    [Name],
    AVG( [Time] ) AS AverageTime
FROM
(
    SELECT
        NAME,
        DATEDIFF( hour, START_DATE, END_DATE ) AS [Time]
    FROM
        dbo.DB1
    GROUP BY
        NAME,
        START_DATE,
       END_DATE
) AS subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this ,

```
SELECT NAME, AVG(DATEDIFF(HOUR, START_DATE, END_DATE))
FROM [dbo].[DB1]
GROUP BY NAME
```